# grep on a Java Method

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting, grep, java

Lets say I have a java class called DirectAction

some of the methods in the class have the word "action" or "Action"

What is the grep command to get the names of all the methods who have "Action" or "action" and write it to an external file?

Example:

```
public class DirectAction extends ERXDirectAction {

/**
 * 
 * @param aRequest
 */
public DirectAction(WORequest aRequest) {

}

// ============================================================================================
// ACTIONS

/**
 * Default Action
 * 
 */
@docDirectAction
public WOActionResults defaultAction() {

}

/**
 * @return goes to login page for student
 */
@docDirectAction
public WOActionResults studentAction() {
    );
    return nextPage;
}

/**
 * @return goes to Admin login page
 */
@docDirectAction
public WOActionResults adminAction() {
    return nextPage;
}

/**

 * @return calls the AdminAction
 */
@docDirectAction
public WOActionResults staffAction() {

    return adminAction();
}
```

}

I want to get only the below output.

```
public class DirectAction extends ERXDirectAction

public DirectAction(WORequest aRequest)

public WOActionResults defaultAction()

public WOActionResults studentAction()

public WOActionResults adminAction()

public WOActionResults staffAction()
```

NOTE: the only word that is common in all these methods is "Action" or "action"

Also please use only grep if possible :)

Comment: If possible, I suggest you run this `grep` command on the output of `javap -private DirectAction.class` instead of `DirectAction.java`, because that will give you just the method names. (javap is a printer for java bytecode.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to return only the matching text (instead of the whole line), you need the `-o` flag

```
grep -o 'public .*[a|A]ction.*)'
```

or with extended regular expressions

```
grep -Eo 'public .*[aA]ction.*\)' file
```

Or, extended for any lines beginning with pub(lic), pri(vate) or pro(tected)

```
grep -Eo '^(pub|pri|pro).*[aA]ction.*\)' file
```

Comment: Tried that too, but sometimes the methods could be private or protected... So that will become too many greps in one line. Which gets annoying .

Comment: grep -o 'p[a-z]* .*[a|A]ction.*)' DirectAction.java

Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Not `grep`, but...

```
sed -n '\|DirectAction|{/^@/n;/{/s|||;p}'
```

Returns me these results:

```
public class DirectAction extends ERXDirectAction
public DirectAction(WORequest aRequest)
public WOActionResults defaultAction()
public WOActionResults studentAction()
public WOActionResults adminAction()
public WOActionResults staffAction()
```

Basically I just address lines that contain the phrase `DirectAction`. I then check to see if the first character on the line is an `@` and - if so - I overwrite the current line with the `n`ext line. Next I look for a `{` and if found I remove it. Then I `p`rint.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -i action( <file>
```

The `-i` makes the search case insensitive, and I added the `(` at the end of `action` because it appears that all the things you expect to see have a paren at the end, but you could just leave it out.

For the record, this is the simplest use of `grep` you'll find; reading the man page would have revealed this solution very quickly.

Comment: I did that :)It doesnt work :/

Comment: Care to be more specific?

Comment: The output is not as expected, its printing the return adminAction()
Which I dont need, then it is also returning "{" at the end. I want that to be ignored too.